# Nagios: NSCA distributet server - maunal checking works, while automatic checking gives error

Tags: ubuntu, distributed, nagios

I am trying to set up a distributed server with an Ubuntu as main and other one as distributed. The NSCA can send the checks if I am testing it manually. But if it does the checks automatically, I get this error:

```
Warning: Attempting to execute the command /path/to/script/submit_check_results
"etc""etc" "etc" "etc" `resulted in a return code of 126.
Make sure the script or binary you are trying to execute actually exists
```

I have set all rights for the script to Nagios and cofigured the configs accordingly.

**What do I have to do so automatic checking will function properly and I won't get this error ?**

Comment: If it emits an exit code 126 on purpose, you will probably need to wrap it somehow.  Chances are you haven't checked the path properly, though. Are you completely sure `/path/to/script` is correct?

Comment: yes the path is correct.

Comment: what exactly do you mean that i need to wrap it somhow?

Comment: If the script's exit code is unacceptable, write another script which calls this one, then returns an acceptable exit code. Take care to distinguish between zero (success) and nonzero (failure).